# Alfresco Java using 100% CPU

Tags: linux, java, alfresco

Every time I start the alfresco service htop shows that /opt/alfresco/java/bin/java is using 100% and when i click F5 to see child processes I can see that it is creating more and more of the same process, it looks like this:

```
root     28300  100 16.2 3125384 658028 ?      Sl   17:32   0:20 /opt/alfresco/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/alfresco/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dalfresco.home=/opt/alfresco -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/alfresco/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /opt/alfresco/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/alfresco/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/alfresco/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/alfresco/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/alfresco/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

I checked on the old server that I migrated alfresco from and it has the same java process with not even 1% CPU usage and no children. I running alfresco 5.0.

Comment: Does the CPU usage every drops or it keeps running at 100%? Could you share more of a process tree? Is the old server and new server running the same version of Alfresco and what's different between them (OS version, hardware, etc.)? Did you try to use some of the JDK tools (jstack, jcmd, etc.) to get more details? Java Missiong Control may come handy too.

Comment: I fixed it. There was some extra libreoffice PID that the old server didn't have when I ran ps aux | grep libreoffice so I removed it. Now it's weird that the new server is using less RAM, each java process is using 24MB RAM, on the old server it's 32. Also whenever I do anything on the site, the CPU jumps double then on the old server.